# Quartz Scheduler is not working in war file

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, quartz-scheduler

i am new on grails technology . now i am going to write a scheduler with grails so i am facing trouble there.

**Quartz version 2.2.1**
   **Grails version 2.3.7**

1)  This is My Job.

```
public class OrderFetchJob implements Job {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(OrderFetchJob.class);
    public OrderFetchJob() {
    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Hello!  HelloJob is executing. " + new Date());
        GlobalAppService globalAppService =    
        SpringsUtil.getBean(SpringsUtil.GLOBAL_APP_SERVICE);
        globalAppService.startApplication();
    } 
}
```

2)  This is my scheduler.

```
    public class OrderFetchScheduler {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(OrderFetchScheduler.class);

    private static OrderFetchScheduler JOB_SCHEDULER = new OrderFetchScheduler();
    private Scheduler scheduler = null;

    public OrderFetchScheduler() {
    }

    public static OrderFetchScheduler getInstance() {
        return JOB_SCHEDULER;
    }

    public void startup() {
        try {
            // and start it off
            scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

            // define the job and tie it to our OrderFetchJob class
            JobDetail job = newJob(OrderFetchJob.class).withIdentity("job1",
                    "group1").build();

            // Trigger a job that repeats every 20 seconds

            Trigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *")).build();
            Trigger trg = scheduler.getTrigger(trigger.getKey());
            if (trg == null) {
                // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
                scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
                log.debug("if");
            } else {

                TriggerBuilder tb = trg.getTriggerBuilder();
                Trigger trigger1 = tb.withSchedule(
                        cronSchedule("0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *")).build();
                scheduler.rescheduleJob(trg.getKey(), trigger1);
                log.debug("else");

            }
            scheduler.start();

            log.debug("success");

        } catch (SchedulerException se) {
            log.debug(se);
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        try {
            scheduler.shutdown();
            log.debug("shutdown");

        } catch (SchedulerException se) {
            log.debug(se);
        }
    }
}
```

3)  this is conf/Quartz.properties

```
#    Configure Main Scheduler Properties

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyClusteredScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO


#    Configure ThreadPool   

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

#   Configure JobStore

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000

# Configure Datasources

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?   
useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery=select 0 from dual
```

4)  finally added this jars in lib folder.

```
1) c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar
2) quartz-all-2.1.1.jar
```

this is perfectly working with IDE.
but when i create war file and deploy 
   tomcat then job and trigger is not going to persist in **mysql server 5.5.30**
   tomcat version is **apache-tomcat-7.0.42**

Answer (score 1):

finally after so much trouble i short out this issue just change the name quartz.properties instead of Quartz.properties file name.

thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler will not start without calling your `OrderFetchScheduler.startup()` method. Where did you call this method in your web-app?

MyStartUp.java

```
package com.you.web;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class MyStartUp implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // call your Scheduler startup function
        Example : 
        new OrderFetchScheduler().startup()
    }
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

Configure in `web.xml`

```
<web-app ...>
    ...
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.you.web.MyStartUp</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```